# Compare HashMap value variables with other variable (Java 8 - Streams)

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it posible to write this method a bit more clear using streams in Java 8?

```
public static boolean doCompareEmail( UserDataAttribute data )
{

    Map<String, User> users = loadUsersByFilter();

    for( Map.Entry<String, User> user : users.entrySet( ) )
    {
        if( user.getKey( ).equals( data.getValue() ) )
        {
            return !data.getEmail().equals( user.getValue( ).getEmail() );
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.anyMatch()`

```
return users.entrySet().stream()
                       .anyMatch(u -> u.getKey().equals(data.getValue())
                                      && !data.getEmail().equals(u.getValue().getEmail()));
```

Here your if condition can be simplified as

```
if( user.getKey().equals( data.getValue()) 
          && !data.getEmail().equals( user.getValue().getEmail()) ){
    return true;
}
```